# Shell scripting and regex: Which one is better to match numbers, [[:digit:]] or [0-9]?

Tags: bash, unix-shell, regular-expressions

As the title suggests, which one is better to match numbers, `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`?

I'm using the bash shell

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "better" ? if both achieve the same goal, both are good enough solution unless you have extra requirements you haven't mentioned.

Comment: hmm I'm thinking about performance, readability and portability, even though the first has been already answered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason that `[[:digit:]]` *must* be used is to support locales that use digits other than `0-9`. For example Arabic-Indic Numerals: `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` (Unicode U+0660 through U+0669). Otherwise for the Hindu-Arabic numerals `0123456789`, `[0-9]` works equally as well as `[[:digit:]]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
# time grep -oE '[[:digit:]]' /etc/services
...
real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.013s


# time grep -oE '[0-9]' /etc/services
...
real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.012s
```

I could probably write a quick script to average them, and I bet I'd find that the averages are identical, but it certainly gives you the idea.

Comment: http://gist.github.com/456559

Comment: +1, I was so focused on summing/averaging that it didn't occur to me to just time the whole big glob.  Well-played.